# How do I compile ROS from source using a forked ros_comm

Tags: ros, wstool, rosinstall, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to compile ROS from source. To do this, I can follow the instructions from http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source, specifically the lines

```
rosinstall_generator ros_comm --rosdistro indigo --deps --wet-only > indigo-ros_comm-wet.rosinstall 
wstool init -j8 src indigo-ros_comm-wet.rosinstall
```

However, I want to use my own forked version of ros_comm packages from https://github.com/asundaresan/ros_comm

It is not clear to me how I can build a bare-bones ROS from source using the above forked version. I'd be grateful for any pointers or instructions for the same. I could not find any.

Thanks,
Aravind.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219141/how-do-i-compile-ros-from-source-using-a-forked-ros_comm/) by [Aravind](https://answers.ros.org/users/19767/aravind/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2015-10-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't tried this solution myself. But this may work:

1. Add `--upstream` option to `rosinstall_generator ros_comm ..` command:

```
rosinstall_generator ros_comm --upstream --rosdistro indigo --deps --wet-only > indigo-ros_comm-wet.rosinstall
```

2. Modify `indigo-ros_comm-wet.rosinstall` and change the URI of `ros_comm` repo to your own fork. Make sure to change the `version` field to appropriate branch/tag of your fork.

```
    - git:
    local-name: ros_comm
    uri: https://github.com/asundaresan/ros_comm
    version: 1.11.15
```

To ensure maximum compatibility, it is a good practice to rebase your changes on top of the current stable version of `ros_comm`. *1.11.15* in this case.

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2015-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aravind](https://answers.ros.org/users/19767/aravind/) on 2015-10-16**:
Thanks! That works.

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2015-10-17**:
You are welcome.